# What is the limit for throttling while using graph API for sharepoint(files and lists)?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

There are limits given for outlook and teams at the link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/throttling.
What is the limit after which the throttling starts for graph API calls for SharePoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint decided not to publish their throttling limits see the following abstract from [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/how-to-avoid-getting-throttled-or-blocked-in-sharepoint-online#why-cant-you-just-tell-me-the-exact-throttling-limits).

> Setting and publishing exact throttling limits sounds straightforward, but in fact it would result in more restrictive limits. We continually monitor resource usage on SharePoint Online. Depending on usage, we fine-tune thresholds so users can consume the maximum number of resources without degrading the reliability and performance of SharePoint Online

If you'd like to request SharePoint to publish their limits, you can add an idea to [UserVoice](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com).